# add dash after three characters in input type number

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular project, I had input type number I need to add a dash after three characters. if add input type number is not working for me if add input type text its working fine.

```
<input type="number" id="bank-code" (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)" [value]='value' maxlength="7" required />

onKey(event){
  var ele = event.split('-').join('');
  if(ele.length > 0){
    ele = ele.match(new RegExp('.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");
  }
  this.value = ele;
}
```

Comment: Input type number does not allow non-numeric characters (because it's type=number). Notice you can input `e` character - it's because `e` is valid number

Comment: besides, it sounds like you're using `angular`. I would tag it.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek thanks you for your replay any solution for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input type number does not allow non-numeric characters (because it's type=number). Notice you can input `e` character - it's because `e` is a valid number.

Try to use input type `tel` with `pattern` attribute, e.x.:

```
<input id='phone-num' type='tel' pattern="[0-9\-]+">
```